# Why there is a "d" in the target name when I build libraries in Visual Studio sometimes?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, build, static-libraries

I want to understand this behavior of Visual Studio (2010) **when I build certain libraries with the target name `X`, the result become `Xd.lib` for Debug build & `X.lib` for Release build**. I was building `CPPUnit`, if that matters

I checked the Debug settings but couldn't find where the "d" come from.

- The `TargetName` (in Configuration Properties - General) is **`$(ProjectName)`**
- The `TargetExtension` (same place) is **`.lib`**

From this, I really don't know where the `d` comes from.

I would be happy with explanation / being pointed to the right docs about this.

Comment: Just guessing here, not a definitive answer: I would imagine that `d` stood for "*debug*".

Comment: yes, i believe so. but would there be a settings that set this 'd' ? I have another project that create "X.lib" in debug mode

Comment: hmm, I found that the property in:
Configuration Settings - Librarian - General -> OutputFile affects the output file's name